# React JS Update an object from an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects in my react state.

```
[
  {
    id: 'd8t4gf',
    title: 'Working on',
    items: [{ title: 'Item 1' }, { title: 'Item 2' }, { title: 'Item 3' }],
  },
  {
    id: '8jy8g',
    title: 'Done',
    items: [{ title: 'Item 1' }, { title: 'Item 2' }],
  },
]
```

I'm trying to update the items of the second object like so.

```
const handleAddNewItemSubmit = (title, id) => {
  const listIndex = lists.findIndex((list) => list.id === id);

  const newData = [...lists];

  newData[listIndex].items = [...newData[listIndex].items, { title }];

  setLists(newData);
};
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating the existing state (specifically, an array object - eg `lists[0]`), which should never be done in React. What you're doing may *happen* to work, but it's not a good way.

Try something like this instead, cloning *everything* along the way down to the nested `items` property:

```
const handleAddNewItemSubmit = (title, id) => {
  setLists(
    lists.map(list => list.id !== id ? list : ({
      ...list,
      items: [...list.items, { title }]
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Looks like I have to learn more about react state management, can you suggest any resource where I should about it?

Comment: There isn't any direct mutation of array in the state, all complexe mutation are perform on the copy  data `const newData = [...lists];`

Comment: @YvesKipondo The problem is the `newData[listIndex].items =`. `newData` is a shallow copy, not a deep copy. `newData[listIndex]` which gets mutated is a reference to a state object, not a new object.

Comment: @vajad57 "Avoid mutation" is pretty much the only hard and fast rule I know you absolutely should follow everywhere. Nothing else with regards to state management comes anywhere close in importance, I think

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleAddNewItemSubmit = (title, id) => {
  const listIndex = lists.findIndex((list) => list.id === id);

  const newData = [...lists];

  newData[listIndex].items = [...newData[listIndex].items, { title }];

  setLists(newData);
};
```

In the above code, when you do `const newData = [...lists]` it just do shallow copy, i.e., only the top level references will be different but if there are any nested objects, they'll have same references as of `lists`.

So when yo do `newData[listIndex].items` you are actually referring to the same object i.e., `lists[listIndex].items`. Since `newData[listIndex].items` is an array which in turn is an object it'll have the same reference as of `lists[listIndex].items`.

So, ultimately you end up mutating the state. In order to avoid that, we can do the state update in different ways

```
const handleAddNewItemSubmit = (title, id) => {
  setLists(oldLists => oldLists.map(list =>
    list.id === id ? ({
      ...list,
      items: [...list.items, { title }]
    }) : list))
}
```

Below I have simulated two examples one which mutates top level object, another which mutates nested objects after spreading.

```js
let lists = [
  {
    id: 'd8t4gf',
    title: 'Working on',
    items: [{ title: 'Item 1' }, { title: 'Item 2' }, { title: 'Item 3' }],
  },
  {
    id: '8jy8g',
    title: 'Done',
    items: [{ title: 'Item 1' }, { title: 'Item 2' }],
  },
];

const addNewTitleOnTopLevel = (title) => {
  const newData = [...lists];
  newData.push({id: '123', title});
  
  //Since doing `[...lists]` will do a shallow copy, the lengths will be different;
  console.log(newData.length, lists.length);
  //The objects are different so, it'll be false.
  console.log(newData === lists);
}

const addNewTitleInnerItems = (title, id) => {  
  const listIndex = lists.findIndex((list) => list.id === id);  
  const newData = [...lists];
  newData[listIndex].items = [newData[listIndex].items, {title}]
  
  //Since `newData[listIndex].items` & `lists[listIndex].items` 
  //are pointing to same references, their length will be same
  console.log(newData[listIndex].items.length, lists[listIndex].items.length);
  //To know if they both are same or not
    console.log(newData[listIndex].items === lists[listIndex].items);
}

addNewTitleOnTopLevel("test");
addNewTitleInnerItems("test", '8jy8g');
```